# Generate JSON test data from RAML

Tags: json, raml

Is there a tool that allows me to create random JSON test data starting from a [RAML](http://raml.org/) file?

Example: starting from a RAML file describing an API generate random static JSON responses to register in a [WireMock](http://wiremock.org/) mock server mappings so that I can run automated tests against the API.

I'm working with Java but tools/libraries in other languages would fit too.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Maybe one of these suits your needs:

- [RAML Mock Server](https://github.com/ozwolf-software/raml-mock-server): Library for validating MockServer calls against a RAML API specification
- [RAML Tester](https://github.com/nidi3/raml-tester): Test if a request/response matches a given raml definition
- [soapui-raml-plugin](https://github.com/SmartBear/soapui-raml-plugin)

  - Allows you to import RAML files into SoapUI for testing your REST APIs
  - Allows you to generate a REST Mock Service for a RAML file being imported

Otherwise check: http://raml.org/projects/projects and filter by type 'test' and language.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks mate  :)

Comment: soapui raml plugin is not suitable for complex .raml files.some are not supported like tokens,O2A

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps https://github.com/wavesoft/raml-lipsum might be useful.
That seems to indicate that it can do as you ask. I didn't think that the other answers seemed to generate sample requests for a raml service, which is I think what the question asks for, and I was asked today at work.